# How to implement "login remember me" using cookies in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I feel quite confused, do not understand what is the difference between res.cookie and req.cookies. And more strangely, I have found that if I do not set a cookie:

```
//The value will be:
req.cookies.uid=="undefined"
//instead of:
req.cookies.uid==undefined
```

Why the express.js design the cookie like this?

If I want to implement a "remember me" function while users trying to log in and set the cookie expire time to infinite or maybe a year, how should I use the cookie correctly?

I have found that the cookieParser only support thing like this:

```
express.cookieParser("secret")
```

And does not support expire/maxAge setting.

Comment: I recommend express-session over cookie-session because in the first the data saved on the server which is more secure .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`res.cookie` is actually a function with a signature of [`res.cookie(key, value, opts)`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie). You can use it to *set* a client's cookie values/options. On the other hand, [`req.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.cookies) is an object that gives you the client's current cookie values. Here's an example using cookies to track page views:

```
var counter = 0;
app.get('/counter', function(req, res) {
    res.cookie('counter', ++counter);

    if (!req.cookies.counter) {
        res.send('This is your first visit!');
    } else {
        res.send('This is visit number '+ req.cookies.counter +'!');
    }
});
```

If you use the [`express.cookieSession()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieSession) middleware, you can set application wide default cookie properties. For example, the cookie's `maxAge` property determines how many milliseconds in the future the cookie will expire, so here I set it to expire in one hour:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession({ secret: 'secret', cookie: { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 }});
// ... your middleware and routes
```

Otherwise, you could set the cookie options individually by passing an options object to `res.cookie()`.

Comment: I tried write res.cookie(uid,uid_value,options). The res.cookie has value, but if I try use console.log to ouput the req.cookies.uid, it is still undefined. Are you sure that the req and res cookie are the same thing?

Comment: No, I didn't say they were the same. `res.cookie()` is a function used to set cookies. `req.cookies` is an object representation of the cookies a client currently has. Another way of putting this is that `res.cookie()` tells the client to set a cookie, and `req.cookies` gives you the cookies a client has set (which were sent with the HTTP request.)

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Since the req.cookies is sent from the request, changing req.cookies will never change the cookies on the client side, so the req.cookies is like a reader and the res.cookie is like a writer, right?

Comment: Yeah exactly! So what happens is Express has a piece of middleware that will read the raw HTTP request headers to pull out the `Cookie` header information. It then uses that data to fill in `req.cookies`. `res.cookie()` adds a `Set-Cookie` header to the raw HTTP response. It's simply a nicer interface then dealing with the HTTP request directly.

Comment: The explanation is good, but the example is a bit flawed. This example works only if there is just one user visiting the URL. The counter is a global variable, which is updated every time *any* browser visits the page. So user1 visits, gets "this is your first visit", count= 1, then user 2 visits, gets "this is your first visit, and count = 2. If user 1 refreshes, he gets count = 3. You can simulate this by hitting the url multiple times from 2 distinct browsers.

Comment: You're right Cheeso that this isn't very useful production code, but I hope it does illustrate the use of cookies in express well enough.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest that your refer to the following [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049294/change-cookie-expiration-in-express). What your looking for is the below code. It allowed you to set the max age of each cookie.

```
if(remember){
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 2628000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an express middleware that does just that: https://github.com/mdarveau/session-rememberme