# Connect-Mongo Expiration Time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, mongoose

Maybe i did not understand right how connect-mongo works.

When i set

```
app.use(express.session({
       secret: '1234567890QWERTY',
       cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60},
       store: new MongoStore({
       db: "DB"
   }),
})
```

This suggest that the session expire after 1 minute.

But my doubt is: if the user refresh the page and on Mongo the session is refreshes too, why after 1 minute the mongo remove the entry?

I want expire the session  after 1 minute, but only when user exit or stop interact with browser.

What is the better form to use session how i need?

Thanks.

add:

Oficial Doc

Note: By connect/express's default, session cookies are set to expire when the user closes their browser (maxAge: null). In accordance with standard industry practices, connect-mongo will set these sessions to expire two weeks from **their last 'set'**. **You can override** this behavior by manually setting the maxAge for your cookies -- just keep in mind that any value less than 60 seconds is pointless, as mongod will only delete expired documents in a TTL collection every minute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well i got the solution

Ref: [Express.js and connect-mongo session duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278355/express-js-and-connect-mongo-session-duration?rq=1)

Ref: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/670

Ref: https://github.com/fealaer/liltael.com/issues/4

thanks @Ivan