# How do you set an inactivity session timeout in SailsJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, sails.js

How do you set a timeout after a certain period of inactivity in the SailsJs framework?

I have managed to set the absolutely session timeout in the `config\session.js` configuration file.

`cookie: {
    maxAge: 15 * 60 * 1000 // 15 minutes.
},`

but this will invalidate the session after 15 minutes regardless of user activity.

Is there a sails configuration setting that I need to update/add, or is it an express session configuration that needs to be updated?

I have tried updating these 2 things in a policy, but it has made no difference.

`req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + (15 * 60 * 1000));
req.session.cookie.maxAge = 15 * 60 * 1000;`

I have also tried using:

`req.session.touch();`

but the session timeout does not update from the moment it is initially set (in the `config\session.js` configuration)

Comment: Take a look at this answer and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199824/sails-js-rolling-sessions

Comment: thank you! This works perfectly