# Cookies expire when browser close in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, browser

I always set **cookies** in **express.js** by executing command,

```
res.cookie("name", "value");
```

But when I close the browser and open again, I saw there is no such cookie.

How can I keep remain cookies forever even if I close the browser? Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change cookie expiration in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049294/change-cookie-expiration-in-express)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using cookie-parser package. And for expiration, just use maxAge attribute.

```
    res.cookie("myCookie", true, {
      maxAge: 1000*60*60*24
    });
```

1000 miliseconds*60 seconds * 60 mins * 24 hour = 1 day. Your cookie will stay in your browser for one day.